# How can I use equation or formula or expression under different situation?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I have noticed that these three words all have the meaning that use several letters, numbers or symbols to represent some.

But I always misuse them in some context? Such as how to describe a mathematical expression? use equation or formula? Or in a programming language. I noticed that most of the code, we call it expressions. Can I describe it as equation?

Comment: "Equation" really involves one thing equalling another, so you'd normally expect to see an = sign in there.

Comment: A dictionary might shed some light here.

Comment: @ralph.m it seems that all these three words need a `=` sign in some situation.

Comment: I've closed this because the research is now in the answer, but OP has not been back to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken @Jim 's advise, and look up the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. And I have found this.

formula, in mathematics, usually a series of letters, numbers or symbols that represent a rule or law

expression usually be used in programming language, or in mathematics. It means a group of signs that represent an idea or a quantity.

While, equation is a statement showing that two amounts or values are equal.

So I can make a conclusion that mostly formula is used to describe a law. And equation is just a statement which can be very simple. And expression shows a feeling or used in a programming language to describe a assignment or computation.